# Get the body of all nodes that match a criterion in an Org Mode document

Tags: org-mode

Given an org document, I'd like to traverse all the nodes (headlines) that have the following property `ARTICLE_TYPE`, and extract the body (excluding the drawers) for each one.

I'm struggling to find the appropriate `org-element-map` expression that will give me this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want. It does assume there is no nesting of the headlines.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results code
(org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer)
    'headline
  (lambda (hl)
    (when (org-element-property :ARTICLE_TYPE hl) 
      (buffer-substring-no-properties
       (save-excursion
     (goto-char (org-element-property :begin hl))
     (org-end-of-meta-data)
     (point))
       (org-element-property :contents-end hl)))))
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Apparently this returns only the result for the first headline that matches (no idea why it doesn't return all).


(Rant: Generally, for a package as good as org mode, I'm a bit shocked at how poor/nonexistent the API is. I would have expected a way to traverse all headlines in whatever order I like (e.g. BFS vs DFS), as well as things like "Return all children of this node" and so on).

(BTW, learned a lot from your blog in the past - thanks!)

Comment: For me, this returns all the nodes.  org-element-map has an optional argument that stops at the first match, but I don't use it in this example.

Comment: Marking as correct, as it seems to work for you. Probably something wrong on my setup and I haven't had time to debug.